# Foreach em PHP processo inverso

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte foreach():

```
$i = 1;
foreach($listagem as $valor){
echo $i; // O que vai me retornar: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 100
$i++;
}
```

Como eu faço para fazer o processo inverso?
Gostaria de retornar: 100, 99, 98, 97, ..., 1

Comment: `$i = 100;` ...laço... `$i--`.

Comment: Explica melhor o que você quer conseguir porque isso está estranho. Pra que `$listagem` se você só usa o `$i`?

Comment: Minha ideia é montar uma contagem de registros, como ele está em forma de lista.. na ordem DESC, gostaria de enumerar também na ordem DESC

Comment: Se os registos vem por ordem decrescente do banco de dados é só utilizar um `foreach` normal que já vai passar pelos registos na ordem inversa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creio que seja isso,

```
$i = 100;
foreach($listagem as $valor){
echo $i; // O que vai me retornar: 100, 99, 98 ...
$i--;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Inicialize a contagem do total de itens

```
$i = count( $listagem );
foreach($listagem as $valor){
    echo $i; // 100, 99, 98, etc
    $i--;
}
```

Comment: tem que ser  $i = count( $listagem ) -1; , pois é -1 por causa do  0 que o array inicia

Answer (score 3):

No teu exemplo não faz sentido utilizar um `foreach`, poderia utilizar normalmente o `for` com decremento:

```
for($index = count($listagem); $index > 0; $index--) {
    echo $index;
}
```

E caso precise exibir os itens do `array`, em ordem decrescente como informou, basta acessar o elemento:

```
for($index = count($listagem); $index > 0; $index--) {
    echo $listagem[$index];
}
```

Comment: Eu uso o foreah() para trazer os resultados do banco de dados, que estão dentro do array ($listagem)

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a duvida no nosso amigo não seja sobre exibir uma variável em sequencia decrescente, mas sim o conteúdo do array em ordem decrescente, então se houver um array com o conteúdo:

```
$listagem = Array(1, 2, 3... 100);
```

ele queira exibir:

```
100 99 98... 1
```

Para isso a própria instrução "*foreach*" pode ser usada, pois será possível  a execução tanto para para array simples, como para array que o índice seja nomeado:

```
$listagem = Array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3... '???' => 100);
```

Para isso se deve incluir a a instrução "**array_reverse**" para que o **foreach** (que seque o conteúdo como uma fila), liste o array em ordem invertida (como uma estrutura de pilha), para isso o código pode ficar da seguinte forma:

```
foreach ( array_reverse($listagem) as $valor) {
  # Manipupação da variável $valor, ex:
  echo print_r($valor, true), '<br />';
}
```

Ou, caso queira utilizar o índice:

```
foreach ( array_reverse($listagem) as $indice => $valor) {
  # Manipupação das variáveis $indice e $valor, ex:
  echo $indice, ':', print_r($valor, true), '<br />';
}
```

Espero não ter complicado demais com as explicações, e que a resolução seja satisfatória a necessidade.